# How to emigrate old statistics to google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

In our project we stored all users event data in our database for over one year , but it's not indexed.

now we are going to use google analytics to store our analytics and analyze the report using google analytics dashboard.

but before start using google analytics , i would like to emigrate all old statics (about 2 million events) to google analytics.

for this matter i should use [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) and it's limit allow me to transfer 2 million hits with no problem.

but i didn't succeed to know how to set the time of the event. Measurement Protocol has [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) but google says :

> Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

how it's possible to transfer **2 million events** to google analytics with there **event time** ?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't. I'm not sure one can say much more about that.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thank you for your comment, but can you think about any work around maybe by using custom dimensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct you can use the measurement protocol to send events data directly to google analytics.  I don't see any problem in sending 2 million events.   However its not possible to set the event time longer then four hours ago.

Queue time is used to set the time that the event occurred as you can see it cant be more then four hours ago and I have found that if you do set it to four hours ago its a bit fuzzy if the data is correct or not.  This feature is probably most use in mobile devices where they may go off line for a short time you can store the data then send it all once the device is online again.

So the dates will be the date that you **sent** the event to Google Analytics you cant back date the data to more then four hours ago.  So I am not sure how much use the data will be to you when it is all inserted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you have any work around , maybe by using custom dimensions ?

Comment: wont matter you still wont be able to get any useful analytics out of 2 million rows inserted today with a custom dimension of some date a year ago.   Everything is going to be analyzed as if it was all the hits happened today.    Have you considered putting your data in big query and using that to analyze it?

Comment: the problem that we need to stop storing statistics in our database and move all the management to google analytics. because it's simple ! we have not used bigquery but we used keen.io

Comment: just start recording to Google analytics now.   You like a lot of others in the past may have to accept that the old data you had stored is not valid in todays world.

Comment: can you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101815/how-to-count-newusers-per-device-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, but you can make it easier on yourself.

Unfortunately, there is no way to add, remove, or otherwise edit Google Analytics hit data retrospectively, except to delete all of it. You also cannot copy, or move it between accounts, or download it all.

You are not the first to have to come to terms with this.

In this situation, we recommend to our clients that they run their new and old systems in parallel for a testing period (usually 6 months or a year), before switching off one of them.

Yes, it's difficult to let go of old data, but sometimes it has to be done.

Comment: can you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101815/how-to-count-newusers-per-device-google-analytics

Comment: @david Sorry, I don't do app analytics.

Comment: Thanks no worries. but it's has the same principle.